# linssid only displaying an empty form (version 2.9)

Tags: 18.04, package-management, output

The ubuntu package for linssid (ubuntu 18.04 LTS) is actually broken (containing linssid version 2.9).

After download and installing the debian package - linssid version 3.6 - it is running again.

Comment: Why is the original offered package for Ubuntu 18.04 not ok?

Comment: Is anyone in Ubuntu world interested to know ... and to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can google for linssid version 3.6, download the debian package and install it...
... but my opinion is, that the official offered package should be of a version that works well.